# How to read resp. parse Joomla session data read from database?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, mysql, session, jsession

Is there a way to read respectively parse Joomla session data in PHP as `session_decode()` and `unserialize()` are not working on that values?

In my component I need to read data from all active non-guest sessions (data column in the #__session database table) and check for the existence of certain variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that field data is split into namespaces. Namespace and its data is separated by `|`, so if you use `explode('|',$data)` you will achieve array where odd index element is an data array and each even index element is an namespace. Here is an example how to decode this variable into namespaces:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('data')->from('#__session');
$db->setQuery($query);
$raw_data = str_replace('\0\0\0', chr(0) . '*' . chr(0), (string)$db->loadObject()->data);
$raw_data = explode('|',$raw_data);

$data = array();
for( $idx = 1, $ic=count($raw_data); $idx<$ic; $idx+=2 ) {
    $data[$raw_data[$idx-1]] = unserialize($raw_data[$idx]);
}
```

The `$data` variable will contain session data split into separate array elements where array key is namespace. The default namespace should be first and its index should be `__default`

Comment: Excellent solution! Your code snippet was working right away with Joomla! 3.4.3 Stable.

Comment: Should, I tested it on Joomla 3.4.3, of course this is for single session element. If you want to check all sessions you will need to change it a little bit. Probably create a function from this and use it on every session element. Also remember that if you have many sessions trying to parse all will have huge performance downfall.